# Is there a way to set a breakpoint at the start of any NSLog statement?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, logging, breakpoints

Some part of a big code base is printing out weird `NSLog` statements, and I'm trying to detect where it's coming from. Is there a way to put 1 breakpoint at the start of every `NSLog` call so I can see where it's being called from, rather than manually have to put breakpoints on all places that call `NSLog`?

Comment: Go get DLog, global find and replace all NSLog.

Comment: @Wain That won't work if some binary-only library (e.g. UIKit) is calling `NSLog`.

Comment: I'd probably override the NSLog macro with my own -- one that calls off to a breakpoint hook.

Answer (score 20):

In **Xcode 6**:

**Step 1**:
On the **Navigator** on the left, go to **Breakpoint Navigator** (<kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>):

**Step 2**:
Click the **`+`** button on the bottom left (**Add a new breakpoint**),
then choose **Add Symbolic Breakpoint...**:

[image: screenshot for steps 1 and 2]

**Step 3**:
In **Symbol**, type `NSLog`.

[image: screenshot for step 3]

Alternatively, you can do the same thing in **Debug** → **Breakpoints** → **Create Symbolic Breakpoint**.

Fo **Xcode 5**, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20918385/1).

Answer (score 15):

If you want to break on a certain log message you can use:

[image]

This example will break on every log containing the word "Warning".

Update:
On newer devices use $x0.
Simulator and older use $r0.
$arg0 should do for all cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me solve the issue I was having over in my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281627/finding-the-origin-of-xcode-debug-message

Comment: to save retyping, here's the string: `[(NSString*)$r0 containsString: @"Warning"]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it in xCode 9.3 and I got an error:  `use of undeclared identifier '$r0`. tried this one instead and it worked fine:
`[(NSString*)$arg1 containsString: @"Warning"]`

Comment: Hi Mostafa. On newer devices the registers are marked as x. So $x0 should work in your case.

Answer (score 4):

In the breakpoint navigator (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) add (on the bottom, there is a Plus symbol) a symbolic breakpoint and use `NSLog` as symbol.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) you can set that kind of breakpoint by doing so in the lldb console:

```
breakpoint set --name NSLog
```

One way to do this using Xcode could be to put a breakpoint in the `main` function or on you `AppDelegate` `applicationDidFinishLaunchin` (read: as soon as possible).
Then, you run your app, and when it pauses on said breakpoint, you have access to the lldb console: you type the above line and hit return, and lldb prints something like this:

```
Breakpoint 3: where = Foundation`NSLog, address = 0x32a3da08
```

At this point, you resume your app, and it will pause again when `NSLog` is called (pay attention to the call stack using the Debug Navigator).