# Xcode: How do I tell where a warning is coming from?

Tags: xcode

I get the following warning:`2015-01-01 12:58:52.793 MyApp[15976:282754] Application tried to represent an active popover presentation:<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x17dc5940>`
How do I tell which *File: Line number* is caused the warning?
I assume that `MyApp[15976:282754]` is some place in my application.

Comment: The numbers in `MyApp[15976:282754]` are the process ID and the thread. They are not particularly useful for identifying the file or line number. You can try setting a breakpoint on `NSLog*` and/or `asl_log`.

Comment: How would I set a breakpoint on NSLog?

Comment: Thanks Ken. I set a break point on NSLog as described in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918385/1373313

Comment: And did the breakpoint trip when you reproduced that warning? If so, that should show you where in your code it happened.

Comment: Yes. Turns out that the problem is a bug in iOS 8. It can be triggered by clicking on a date widget in Safari.