# Finding the origin of Xcode debug message

Tags: xcode

I am working with a number of 3rd party suppliers, who have provided me with comprehensive .lib files. One of the processed that are running are logging a message to the console that is a little concerning and needs to be raised with the supplier.
The problem is, I'm not sure where the message is coming from and, due to the complexity of the project, would be pretty much impossible to see where the message is coming from. By this, I mean, that some libraries interact with each other and the project will not run without others. If I were to comment out the initialisation of certain classes, it could be a red-herring as it may be calling a function from another library.
My question is, is there a feature in Xcode breakpoints (or another tool that I may be able to use) that shows where a certain console log (whether it be NSLog or possibly std::cout etc) is coming from?

Thanks a lot, in advance.
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use symbolic breakpoints to break on `NSLog` or `std::cout`. If you are dealing with C++ code or Swift you can even break on specific errors or exceptions. To add symbolic breakpoints to your project, you have to do the following:

- Go to the **breakpoint navigator** by clicking on the icon that looks
  like a fat right arrow on the navigation area (in Xcode 8, 2nd icon
  counting from the right on the panel to the left of the editor)
- Click on the **+ button** on the bottom left corner of the window
- Choose on the pop-menu **Symbolic Breakpoint**
- Add the symbol you want to break on (examples: in C++, `std::cout`; in objective C: `-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`; in C or Swift, `CGErrorBreakpoint()` - **Important Note** - avoid inserting any white space; unfortunately, the formatting in here puts -[symbol] in different lines but there must be no white space between - and [ in the ObjC symbol
- If you know what is the library that is giving you grief fill in the **module** field
- Click on the **action** button and choose **Debugger Command** in the popup menu that comes up
- In the text field below, fill in **`bt`** for getting a backtrace every time you hit such a symbol
- If you don't want to stop execution after hitting the first breakpoint, then check the **Automatically continue after evaluating actions** checkbox

If your library is throwing a C++ exception, you can break on this too. Just choose that option when you click on the + button. To know more how to set breakpoints in Xcode go to:

http://help.apple.com/xcode/

And navigate to: **Debug your app** > **Set Breakpoints** > **Pause execution when events occur**

Comment: Brilliant. This pretty much got me on the right track. I was able to do this and set the condition to `[(NSString*) $r0 containsString:@"Generating"]`, which let me pin point the place that was logging this message out and then get a stack trace back through the problematic library. Shout outs to this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35012840/1197723) answer for helping with the syntax for the condition.

Comment: Glad I could help :)